# javascript files loading for specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am experiencing some issue when loading some javascript file. I am using some jquery plugin and to make it work, I had to add the several required javascript files just before the closing body tag. Now I want these files to be loaded for some specific `url`, so I tried this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.href.indexOf("some url") > -1) {
$.getScript("my_different_files.js");}
});
```

but now the plugin doesn't work (I won't detail the error because I only changed the `javascript` files loading process). What is the best way to mimic the javascript source loading using some `url` conditioned load ?

Comment: have you tried loading the script synchronously ?

Comment: @collapsar yes, same result !

Comment: have you checked the contents of `window.location.href` and `<some_url>`at the time of calling? maybe some problem with url encoding of reserved characters?

Comment: @collapsar yes I checked, it works well

Answer (score 1):

A better approach for such a task would be to use some module loading/management library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). [This is some example code on how you can do that with RequireJS](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)

Comment: thank you but how do I specify some specific js file load for a specific uri with requireJs. (Because I am using `smarty` which generate first header and footer and then loads the content. If I put my js files in the content that is loaded after header and footer, the  jquery plugin fails to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try these [tips.](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html).i think it will suit to you.